# Can you work with char's in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, char

I have a .NET Class that contains a property that returns a char value.
I am accessing this assembly using a VBScript via COM.
When i attempt to read the property that is of type (char) I get an error in my VBScript that reads `Variable uses an Automation type not supported in VBScript`.
How can I get around this error. Is there a way to do it without changing the datatype in the .NET assembly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the char type using the VBScript function chr().
like this: `chr ID = chr(FW.WheelID)` where WheelID is the property of type char of the object FW.